# Erro no Slim framework: chamado require '../Slim/Slim/Slim.php';

Tags: php, slim, slimframework

Erro ao criar ao chamar função Slim.php

**Código:**

```
<?php
    require '../Slim/Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
    $app->get('/', function () {
    echo "SlimProdutos";
});
```

[image: distribuição das pastas]
[image: erro na tela]

Comment: Não seria porque está em minúsculo o nome das pastas?

Comment: slim ou Slim ???

Comment: No seu printscreen as pastas estão ```slim```, mas no seu require elas estão ```Slim```. Não sei se influencia, apenas uma sugestão

Comment: Fiz as alterações e nada..o erro persiste!

Comment: A minha versão do slim : 3.xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebi você está fazendo uso do composer!

Então tente carregar usando o autoload do composer, segue abaixo o exemplo:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
    $app->get('/', function () {
        echo "SlimProdutos";
    });
```